# Scala ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala, jvm

I am learning Scala and getting the exception `ExceptionInInitializerError` while only the custom `MathCalculationException` was expected.

This is the the expression that causes the error:
`println(PocketCalculator1.divide(10, 0))`\

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at lectures.part2oop.SO.main(SO.scala)
Caused by: lectures.part2oop.SO$MathCalculationException1: division by zero
at lectures.part2oop.SO$PocketCalculator1$.divide(SO.scala:34)
at lectures.part2oop.SO$.<clinit>(SO.scala:39)
```

Curiously it would seem that the code below is very much the same code that the instructor
is executing but he does not get this error. I am certainly missing something.

This is the code:

```
package lectures.part2oop

object SO extends  App {
    class OverflowException1 extends RuntimeException
    class UnderflowException1 extends RuntimeException
    class MathCalculationException1 extends RuntimeException("division by zero")


    object PocketCalculator1 {
        def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
            val result = x + y
            if (x > 0 && y > 0 && result < 0) throw new OverflowException1
            else if (x < 0 && y < 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderflowException1
            else result
        }

        def subtract(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
            val result = x - y
            if (x > 0 && y < 0 && result < 0) throw new OverflowException1
            else if (x < 0 && y > 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderflowException1
            else result
        }

        def multiply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
            val result = x * y
            if (x > 0 && y > 0 && result < 0) throw new OverflowException1
            else if (x < 0 && y < 0 && result < 0) throw new OverflowException1
            else if (x > 0 && y < 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderflowException1
            else if (x < 0 && y > 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderflowException1
            else result
        }

        def divide(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
            if (y == 0) throw new MathCalculationException1
            else x / y
        }
    }
    println(PocketCalculator1.divide(10, 0))
}
```

Comment: Don't use `App`, it was a mistake, just write a regular `main` method. That is what is swallowing your exception and producing an initialization error. - BTW, in general, it is very weird to launch exceptions in **Scala**.

Comment: Yes, that will do, thanks. Post your comment as a reply and I will be happy to mark as the accepted answer.